# Gigliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev inequality for functions in $W^{k,p}$, without zero trace.

Tags: inequality, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

The G-N-S inequality can be stated as follows:

Let $U\subset\mathbb R^d$, open bounded, with $C^1$ boundary, then for any $w\in W^{k,p}_0(U)$, $p<d$ $$\|w\|_{L^{p^*}(U)}\le C(d)\|\nabla w\|_{L^2(U)}$$ (Where $p^*=\frac{dp}{d-p}$).

But can in be used for $u\in W^{k,p}(V)$, where $V\subset\subset U$, (compactly contained)? By taking $W$ such that $V\subset\subset W\subset\subset U$, and extending $u$ by $0$ to $\tilde{u}$ in $W$, and considering, $\tilde{u}\in W^{k,p}_0(W)$, and applying G-S-N inequality to $\tilde{u}$, i.e.

$\|u\|_{L^{p^*}(V)}=\|\tilde{u}\|_{L^{p^*}(W)}\le C(d)\|\nabla\tilde u\|_{L^p(W)}=C(d)\|\nabla u\|_{L^p(V)}$

Is this idea correct?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Or is the best that is possible is to use the general sobolev inequality on $u\in W^{1,p}(V)$? where by for $q$ such that $\frac{1}{q}=\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{d}$, i.e. $q=p^*$, we have $$\|u\|_{L^q(V)}=\|u\|_{L^{p^*}(V)}\le C\|u\|_{W^{1,p}(V)}$$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question properly. But unless you have $u\in W^{k,p}_0(V)$, the extension by $0$ will not work. i.e., $\tilde u$ will not be a $W^{k,p}$ function.

Comment: You can't expect an inequality of the form $$\| u\|_{L^p}\leq C\| \nabla u\|_{L^q},$$ for general $u$ in a bounded domain: Consider the constant functions. This is why we need the full $W^{1,p}$ norm on the RHS.

Comment: @Jose27 that makes sense, thanks! What about on unbounded domains?